# clear DOM jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, load, jquery-ui-tabs

I have an interface where I can switch between tabs, and everytime I do that, load() function is called and loads some html to a div.

The thing is, even when I switch to another tab, the previous tab content stays in the DOM, and I don't want that, because I need to have duplicate id's and it's not very a optimal memory usage.

So basically, the question is, how do I clean the DOM from what was loaded before into that div, when I switch to another tab?

It would be even better, if I could name the loaded contents or something and then delete from the DOM, because I can't always know where the contents have been loaded.

Comment: What do you use for the tabs? jQuery UI Tabs or another plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method on the `div`-element that contains the html you want to remove.

If you don't know which element that is, you have to bind the [`select`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#events) event (if you use jQuery UI Tabs) for the tabs so you can store which tab is currently selected and also to know which one was previously selected.

Example:

```
var selectedTab;
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    if (selectedTab) {
        selectedTab.find("div").empty();
    }
    selectedTab = ui.panel;
});
```

You can also bind the above at creation-time of the tabs widget by passing the anonymous function as an option:

```
select: function(event, ui) { ... }
```

Comment: how do you know he is using jQueryUI tabs?

Comment: @jAndy, I don't. But it's the same principle.

Comment: selectedTab = ui.panel; should be before the if statement, not?

Comment: @K Ivanov, why would you want that? Then we wouldn't know which tab was selected before the current one.

Answer (score 1):

@Markus Ekwall:
You need to surround selectedTab.find[...] with jQuery or else you'll get "selectedTab is not a function".

```
$(selectedTab).find("div").empty(); // or jQuery(selectedTab).find("div").empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the select selector, empty out the previously selected tab. This works.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( { select: function(event, ui) {

    var selectedPanel = $("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)");
    $(selectedPanel).empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the div container has `id` just use remove, like:

```
$("#id").remove();
```

in case you are using plain JavaScript:

```
var tab = document.getElementById("id");

if (tab.hasChildNodes())
{
    while (tab.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        tab.removeChild(tab.firstChild);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will remove the container. Bad idea :)